# Ajax 400 bad request from an elastic search filtered query

Tags: json, ajax, elasticsearch, get, bad-request

I want to use Ajax to retrieve data from elasticsearch when the query has a filter.
I'm using GET.

My code is the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : 'HOST/tomo2o/shop/_search',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({"query":{"match":{"catlev1":"Motors"}}}),
            contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I did the 3 things people suggest to do:

1. stringify the json filter
2. set the data type as json
3. set the content type as application/json

But I'm still getting the following error:

```
GET HOST/tomo2o/shop/_search?{%22query%22:{%22match%22:{%22catlev1%22:%22Motors%22}}} 400 (Bad Request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to pass a [DSL query in the query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string) you need to pass it in the `source` parameter and also add a `source_content_type` parameter to indicate the content type

So you can do it like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'HOST/tomo2o/shop/_search',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
           source: JSON.stringify({"query":{"match":{"catlev1":"Motors"}}}),
           source_content_type: "application/json"
        },
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was very helpful just to reference your formatting for the query and the JSON.stringify